# Any specific pattern suggestion for parameters destructuring in functions in ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my React app, I'm calling two functions based on the owner type. The challenge here is, the order in which I'm calling the parameters might differ and based on the condition. Currently, I'm calling each and every param based on the type of owner.

How do I make it more dynamic? Is there a pattern to make it more readable? Could anyone help?

```
const getCarStats = async(
    type,
    model,
    color,
    weight,
    source,
    make,
    year,
    id,
    owner,
  ) => {
    if (owner === 'A') {
      await getAResult(
        weight,
        source,
        make,
        year,
        id,
        owner,
      );
    }
    if (owner === 'B') {
      await getBResult(
        type,
        model,
        color,
        weight,
        make,
        year,
        id,
        owner,
      );
    }
```

Comment: For that many parameters, it would be better to pass a single object with those names as properties, rather than making them positional arguments

Comment: Why don't you pass around a car object? Then you don't have to worry about order of parameters: `const getCarStats = (car) => car.owner === "A" ? getAResult(car) : getBResult(car)`.

Comment: FYI, this is value spreading, not object destructuring.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That could be it but can you please elaborate? I'm not sure if i have followed you correctly on the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could define the two inner functions like this instead:

```
const getAResult = async ({
  weight, source, make, year, id, owner
}) => {
  ...
};

const getBResult = async ({
  type, model, color, weight, make, year, id, owner
}) => {
  ...
};
```

Then the outer function can become much simpler:

```
const getCarStats = async car => {
  if (car.owner === 'A') {
    await getAResult(car);
  }

  if (car.owner === 'B') {
    await getBResult(car);
  }
};
```

Here, `car` is expected to be an object containing properties whose names match the positional parameters that are in the question's implementation.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! Awesome, that helped.

Comment: how this is documneted :

`if (car.owner === 'A') {
    await getAResult(car);
  }`
what are the params here, how would I know? do I have to read the document for API a.. ..`getAResult(car);`

Comment: @xdeepakv it's one parameter, with a self-documenting name. `...rest` is not a self-documenting name and leaves you with the questions "how many parameters" and "what order". With this approach, it's one parameter, and properties on the object are unordered, so it doesn't matter which order you name the properties. Isn't that nice?

Comment: I think that I haven't seen correctly my answer! prejudge is a bad thing! anyways. The function should not have to have this if-else! you may look for the factory design pattern.

Comment: and here car is not documented. If i type, `getCarStats({id` no autocomplete

Comment: @xdeepakv I've looked at your answer multiple times. I've already explained why I don't like your initial approach, and your second approach addresses the comments I've made, but it's just a lot more verbose than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can move common properties in rest.

```
const getCarStats = async(
  type,
  source,
  model,
  ...rest
) => {
  if (owner === 'A') {
    await getAResult(
      source,
      ...rest
    );
  }
  if (owner === 'B') {
    await getBResult(
      type,
      model,
      ...rest
    );
  }
}
```

// Other

```
const getCarStats = async (
  type,
  source,
  model,
  color,
  weight,
  make,
  year,
  id,
  owner
) => {
  const otherParams = {
    color,
    weight,
    make,
    year,
    id,
    owner,
  };
  if (owner === "A") {
    await getAResult(weight, source, otherParams);
  }
  if (owner === "B") {
    await getBResult(type, model, otherParams);
  }
};
```

Comment: If anything, this is worse because the code is no longer self-documenting. At least in the code given in the question, you could tell what the expected parameters were.

Comment: This is dynamic, If you need dynamic, you have to make them dynamic. For document u already have comments.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts What is the point in documenting the function arguments that don't really matter at this specific point? Would they not be self-documented where the other functions are defined? It's pretty clear what the named arguments are, and where the rest go.

Comment: @DrewReese so then you're forced to look at the implementation of `getAResult()` and `getBResult()` just to figure out how you're suppoed to call `getCarStats()`? No, that's not ideal.

Comment: I think we are missing the clean coding chapter here! :-D

Comment: @PatrickRoberts IDK about you, but if I *really* want to know what a function does I go look at its definition *and* implementation. Or if it's already documented, let the IDE's intellisense tell me when I simply hover over the function name.

Comment: @DrewReese exactly, you should be able to hover over any invocation of `getCarStats()` and be able to determine what parameters to pass to it, let alone _how many_. A `...rest` parameter shouldn't be used for a non-variadic, non-homogenous list of arguments.

Comment: Here question was, how to use the ES6 feature, not how to document. If you want to use ES6 rest operator. We have to go with that. Other thing, As we reccomened, We should not have more than 3 param in caller function

Comment: @xdeepakv don't be so literal, they're not specifically asking for _that_ approach, just _any better approach_.

Comment: yes! i already edited my answer. If you see! other suggested way! `A design pattern is choice.`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother to have all those variables separated, but just pass a `car` object tha contains all of them:

```
const getCarStats = async(car) => {
    if (owner === 'A') {
      return await getAResult(car);
    }

    if (owner === 'B') {
      return await getBResult(car);
    }
}
```

Then, in `getAResult` and `getBResult` you can destructuring the object taking only the props you're interested in:

```
function async getAResult({
        weight,
        source,
        make,
        year,
        id
        // owner is omitted because you know is "A"
      }) {
...
}
```

You can also do the destructuring in the function's body.

Comment: In this context, the `await` serves no purpose. `return` is sufficient.